# What methods can one use to solve first-order partial differential equations?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus

This is for a written math assignment (4000 words) and I chose to investigate methods to solve F.O.P.D. equations. Specifically, the goal would be to compare two "most common" methods. I have heard that the Jacobean Matrix is used extensively for this. Is there a "standard" (like typical algebraic) method that would be good to compare?

The purpose of the math assignment is for students to have conceptual understanding of these topics by self-interest/teaching.

Let me know what you think!!

Comment: I'd probably go with the method of characteristics for one and any suitable numerical method for the other.  I'm not familiar with another analytic method for nontrivial first-order PDEs (or maybe I was once and I forgot).

Answer (score 2):

Comparing an analytical method against a numerical one (as suggested by @tilper) may be more beneficial to you personally if you don't already have experience with either. i.e., you get to do some research into both areas, and hopefully learn about the fundamental differences of numerical and analytical techniques.

On the other hand, comparing two numerical methods for example would be (in a sense) easier to talk about in a report. There are often limitations to each numerical method in terms of accuracy and precision, and when they can be applied, a 'pros vs. cons' list could be a useful breakdown in such a report.

In any case, there are many options to choose from. Take a look at [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_partial_differential_equations) link on numerical methods, and [this](http://people.physics.anu.edu.au/~gvn105/analyticMethPDE.pdf) for analytical ones.